# openFrameworks Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ofxiOSEAGLView

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, 64-bit, openframeworks

I try to compile on iOS 8.3, Xcode 6.3.2 a project including openFramework.
It works very well if I setup the compilation for 32bit architecture

```
ARCHS = $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)
```

The problem is, recently, Apple requires iOS apps to be 64bits exclusively.

I tried to change my conf to:

```
ARCHS = $(ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT)
```

or simply to set standard architecture but I end up with the following error:

[image]

with the following conf:

[image: XCode Conf]

```
HEADER_OF = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/openFrameworks/**"
HEADER_OFXIOS = "$(OF_PATH)/addons/ofxiOS/**"
HEADER_OFXMULTITOUCH = "$(OF_PATH)/addons/ofxMultiTouch/**"
HEADER_OFXACCELEROMETER = "$(OF_PATH)/addons/ofxAccelerometer/**"
HEADER_FREETYPE = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/freetype/include"
HEADER_FREETYPE2 = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/freetype/include/freetype2"
HEADER_POCO = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/poco/include"
HEADER_FMODEX = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/fmodex/include"
HEADER_GLEW = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/glew/include"
HEADER_FREEIMAGE = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/FreeImage/include"
HEADER_TESS2 = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/tess2/include"
HEADER_RTAUDIO = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/rtaudio/include"
HEADER_GLU = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/glu/include_ios"
HEADER_SSL = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/openssl/include"
HEADER_OFXASSIMPMODELLOADER = "$(OF_PATH)/addons/ofxAssimpModelLoader/**"

LIB_FREEIMAGE = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/FreeImage/lib/osx/freeimage.a"
LIB_TESS = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/tess2/lib/osx/tess2.a"
LIB_GLU = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/glu/lib/ios/glu.a"
LIB_SSL = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/openssl/lib/osx/ssl.a"
LIB_CRYPTO = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/openssl/lib/osx/crypto.a"

LIB_FREEIMAGE_IPHONE = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/FreeImage/lib/ios/freeimage.a"
LIB_FREETYPE_IPHONE = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/freetype/lib/ios/freetype.a"
LIB_POCOFOUNDATION_IPHONE = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/poco/lib/ios/PocoFoundation.a"
LIB_POCONET_IPHONE = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/poco/lib/ios/PocoNet.a"
LIB_POCONETSSL_IPHONE = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/poco/lib/ios/PocoNetSSL.a"
LIB_POCOCRYPTO_IPHONE = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/poco/lib/ios/PocoCrypto.a"
LIB_POCOUTIL_IPHONE = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/poco/lib/ios/PocoUtil.a"
LIB_POCOXML_IPHONE = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/poco/lib/ios/PocoXML.a"
LIB_POCOZIP_IPHONE = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/poco/lib/ios/PocoZip.a"
LIB_TESS_IPHONE = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/tess2/lib/ios/tess2.a"
LIB_GLU_IPHONE = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/glu/lib/ios/glu-ios.a"
LIB_SSL_IPHONE = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/openssl/lib/ios/ssl.a"
LIB_CRYPTO_IPHONE = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/openssl/lib/ios/crypto.a"
LIB_ASSIMP = "$(OF_PATH)/addons/ofxAssimpModelLoader/libs/assimp/lib/ios/assimp.a"

MISC_FLAGS = "-ObjC"

OF_CORE_LIBS = $(MISC_FLAGS) $(LIB_FREETYPE) $(LIB_FREEIMAGE) $(LIB_POCOFOUNDATION) $(LIB_POCONET) $(LIB_POCONETSSL) $(LIB_POCOCRYPTO) $(LIB_POCOXML) $(LIB_POCOZIP) $(LIB_POCOUTIL) $(LIB_FREETYPE_IPHONE) $(LIB_FREEIMAGE_IPHONE) $(LIB_POCONET_IPHONE) $(LIB_POCONETSSL_IPHONE) $(LIB_POCOCRYPTO_IPHONE) $(LIB_POCOXML_IPHONE) $(LIB_POCOZIP_IPHONE) $(LIB_POCOUTIL_IPHONE) $(LIB_POCOFOUNDATION_IPHONE) $(LIB_TESS_IPHONE) $(LIB_GLU) $(LIB_GLU_IPHONE) $(LIB_SSL_IPHONE) $(LIB_CRYPTO_IPHONE) $(LIB_ASSIMP)
OF_CORE_HEADERS = $(HEADER_OF) $(HEADER_OFXIOS) $(HEADER_OFXMULTITOUCH) $(HEADER_OFXACCELEROMETER) $(HEADER_POCO) $(HEADER_FREETYPE) $(HEADER_FREETYPE2) $(HEADER_FMODEX) $(HEADER_GLEW) $(HEADER_FREEIMAGE) $(HEADER_TESS2) $(HEADER_RTAUDIO) $(HEADER_GLU) $(HEADER_SSL) $(HEADER_OFXASSIMPMODELLOADER)


//THE PATH TO THE ROOT OF OUR OF PATH RELATIVE TO THIS PROJECT.
//THIS NEEDS TO BE DEFINED BEFORE CoreOF.xcconfig IS INCLUDED
OF_PATH = External/openFrameworks

//THIS HAS ALL THE HEADER AND LIBS FOR OF CORE
#include "External/openFrameworks/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/ios/CoreOF.xcconfig"
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig"

OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(PODS_OTHER_LDFLAGS) $(OF_CORE_LIBS)
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(PODS_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS) $(OF_CORE_HEADERS)

// C++ Standard Library
CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY = libstdc++

// Force C99 dialect
GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = c99

// Architectures
ARCHS = $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)
VALID_ARCHS = armv6 armv7 arm64

//C Modules
CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES = NO

//Direct usage of isa
CLANG_WARN_DIRECT_OBJC_ISA_USAGE = YES

//:configuration = Debug
GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT = NO
GCC_WARN_PROTOTYPE_CONVERSION = NO

//:completeSettings = some
GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE = YES

//:completeSettings = some
GCC_WARN_UNINITIALIZED_AUTOS = NO

//:completeSettings = some
GCC_WARN_UNUSED_FUNCTION = NO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try building against the latest OF  main trunk from [here](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/tree/master) or NickHardeman's [ported version of OF](https://github.com/NickHardeman/openframeworks_osx_64)

Comment: No problem , Happy coding !